# Determine the generator of a contractive semigroup acting on bounded measurable functions by a solution to a martingale problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, operator-theory, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $B(E,\mathcal E)$ denote the set of bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable functions from $E$ to $\mathbb R$ equipped with the supremum norm and $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$.

We know that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is contractive, but not necessarily strongly continuous, on $B(E,\mathcal E)$. Let $(\mathcal D(B),B)$ denote the [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup#Infinitesimal_generator) of $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ considered as an operator semigroup on $B(E,\mathcal E)$.

I want to characterize $(\mathcal D(B),B)$ at least on a subset of $\mathcal D(B)$. In order to do that, let $C$ be a closed subspace of $B(E,\mathcal E)$ and $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ be a densely-defined linear operator on $C$.

> One way to show that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous on $C$ and its generator (considered as an operator semigroup on $C$) is $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ (in particular, $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is an extension of $(\mathcal D(B),B)$) is given by a martingale problem approach.
>
> However, I'm really struggling to see what we really need to assume for this.

To elaborate on that, I'm not sure if it's really necessary to assume this, but I think we need to assume that $(E,\mathcal E)$ is a Borel space (i.e. isomorphic to $([0,1],\mathcal B([0,1]))$, e.g. Polish), since then we know that for every probability measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$, there is an unique probability measure $\operatorname P_\mu$ on $\left(E^{[0,\:\infty)},\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}\right)$ with $$\operatorname P_\mu\circ\:\pi_{\{t_0,\:\ldots\:,\:t_n\}}=\mu\otimes\bigotimes_{i=1}^n\kappa_{t_i-t_{i-1}}\tag1$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $0=t_0<\cdots<t_n$, where $\pi_I$ denotes the projection from $E^{[0,\:\infty)}$ onto $E^I$ for $\emptyset\ne I\subseteq[0,\infty)$.

Given that, let $\pi_t:=\pi_{\{t\}}$ for $t\ge0$ and $\delta_x$ denote the Dirac measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ at $x$, $\operatorname P_x:=\operatorname P_{\delta_x}$ and $E_x$ denote the expectation associated to $\operatorname P_\mu$ for $x\in E$.

We easily see that $(\pi_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process on $\left(E^{[0,\:\infty)},\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)},\operatorname P_x\right)$ with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ and initial distribution $\delta_x$ for all $x\in E$.

> Now, assuming that $$\left(f(\pi_t)-\int_0^t(Af)(\pi_s)\:{\rm d}s\right)_{t\ge0}\tag2$$ is an $\mathcal F^\pi$-martingale$^1$ on $\left(E^{[0,\:\infty)},\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)},\operatorname P_x\right)$ for all $f\in\mathcal D(A)$ and $x\in E$, we easily see that $$(\kappa_tf)(x)-f(x)=\int_0^t(\kappa_sAf)(x)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\tag3$$ for all $f\in\mathcal D(A)$ and $t\ge0$. Since $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is contractive on $C$, this implies $$\left\|\kappa_tf-f\right\|_\infty\le t\left\|Af\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{t\to0+}0\tag4$$ for all $f\in\mathcal D(A)$. And since $\mathcal D(A)$ is a dense subset of $C$, we conclude that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous on $C$.
>
> In order to obtain the claim about the generator, I guess we need to assume that $$\kappa_t\mathcal R(A)\subseteq C\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag5,$$ since then the strong continuity on $C$ yields $$\left\|\frac{\kappa_tf-f}t-Af\right\|_\infty\le\sup_{x\in E}\frac1t\int_0^t\left|(\kappa_sAf)(x)-(Af)(x)\right|{\rm d}s\xrightarrow{t\to0+}0\tag6.$$
>
> **Question 1**: Am I missing any crucial assumption? I've found similar results and therein it is assumed that the process $(\pi_t)_{t\ge0}$ is right-continuous and $C$ is separating$^2$. However, I can't see any stage of my proof above where these assumptions are needed.
>
> **Question 2**: Are we able to drop the assumption that $(E,\mathcal E)$ is Borel? For example, if we replace the time scale $[0,\infty)$ by $\mathbb N_0$, we know that the existence of the probability measures $\operatorname P_\mu$ are ensured for *arbitrary* measurable spaces. Is the assumption of being Borel a necessary assumption when we are going from a countable time scale to a continuous one?

---

$^1$ $\mathcal F^\pi$ denotes the filtration generated by $\pi$, i.e. $\mathcal F^\pi_t=\sigma(\pi_s,s\le t)=\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:t]}$ for all $t\ge0$.

$^2$ i.e. if $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $$\int f\:{\rm d}(\mu-\nu)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C\tag7,$$ then $\mu=\nu$.